# Flutter: leading letter instead of icon for ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I think this image is self explanatory of what I want to archive:

[image]

```
ListTile(
              // leading: Icon(Icons.attach_money), <-- this works but I need the currency icon dynamic
              leading: Text(
                "€",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(translate('options.currency')),
              subtitle: Text(translate('options.currency_help')),
              onTap: () {
                showCurrencyPicker(
                  context: context,
                  searchHint: translate('options.search_currency'),
                  showFlag: true,
                  showCurrencyName: true,
                  showCurrencyCode: true,
                  onSelect: (Currency currency) {
                    print('Select currency: ${currency.name}');
                  },
                  favorite: [_options['currency']],
                );
              },
            ),
```

I can show it but I'm not sure how to center it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use PreferredSize, i am testing it and working

```
PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
                // here the desired height
                child: Text("€", style: TextStyle(fontSize:30,height: 1.5),),
              )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works and that was all but I'd like to know how can I force the symbol to be always the same width/font-size (so if it's long the size should be smaller). There are some currencies that use some letters and that breaks the design a little bit adding more padding to the right

Answer (score 0):

You can add a SizedBox, and put the text like this

```
ListTile(
            leading: SizedBox(
              height: 100.0, //desired height
              width: 100.0, //desired width
              child: Text("£", //any currency you want
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                ),
                ),
              ),

            title: ...,
            subtitle: ...
        ),
```